# how to add background image on the top and bottom of the div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```css
body{
 background: url(../img/bedge_grunge.png) repeat;
}
a,a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.background-color{
 background: #fff;
 margin:0 50px 0 50px;
 border-top: 5px solid #00b4bb;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------TOP-BAR---------------------------------------------------------------*/
.before-after-img:before, .before-after-img :after{
 height:8px;
 width: 100%;
 left:0;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnXuL.png) no-repeat;
}
.before-after-img:before{
 top: 0;
}
.before-after-img:after{
 bottom: 0;
}
.before-after-img{
 line-height: normal;
}
.top-bar{
 padding: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Hotel Template 6</title>
 <!-- CSS links -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header class="background-color">
  <section class="top-bar">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="before-after-img">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="address-mail-id">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>ADDRESS
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com">hello@gmail.com</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </header>

 <!-- js links -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
I am new to the stack overflow and i am posting my first question. i want to add the background image on the top and bottom of the div i have tried it but it is not inn a proper form i have attached the background image separately. I have my content with my full code. plz check it once.i think that the css links might be creating a problem.
```

I am new to the stack overflow and i am posting my first question. i want to add the background image on the top and bottom of the div i have tried it but it is not inn a proper form i have attached the background image separately. I have my content with my full code. plz check it once.i think that the css links might be creating a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

I removed `position: relative;` from `.before-after-img` and added it for `.top-bar`

**Note: about your issue**

The issue in your code is you have added `.before-after-img :after` space after selector it should be without space `.before-after-img:after`

```css
body {
  background: url(../img/bedge_grunge.png) repeat;
}
a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.background-color {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  border-top: 5px solid #00b4bb;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------TOP-BAR---------------------------------------------------------------*/

.before-after-img:before,
.before-after-img:after {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnXuL.png) no-repeat;
}
.before-after-img:before {
  top: 0;
}
.before-after-img:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.before-after-img {
  line-height: normal;
}
.top-bar {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header class="background-color">
  <section class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="before-after-img">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="address-mail-id">
              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>ADDRESS
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>  <a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com">hello@gmail.com</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: ya these is it but when i tried in my code i m getting 3 bg images

Comment: i have edited my answer @harshdesai you have added a space after the selector